# How to animate fluid filling down a pipe of any shape?

Tags: unity, 2d, animation

I am working on a project where I want to model a simple flow of fluids around a circuit of pipe. I thought a simple way to do this would be to create an irregular shaped loading bar, then animating the shape as it filled up.

I have found answers for how to create regular loading bars that are rectangle shaped, as well as some for circular loading bars.

But what if want some arbitrary "circuit" of pipes, kind of like one long windey loading bar.

Comment: Presumably then you've tried using a LineRenderer for this purpose? This lets you draw an arbitrary-bent/curved ribbon of geometry, with texture coordinates running the length of it that you can use for animating your fill.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe overkill, but I would use a fluid simulation. They usually simulate small particles that behave like molecules in a fluid (using all the fancy adhesion and cohesion physics stuff).

Be wary though, this will cost you a little bit on the performance-side.